# How to put 2 variables in one if statement

Tags: python-3.x

I don't want it to print 'What is your favourite food when I type Tom or Sister and i put both of them in one if statement but it keep print "what is your favourite food'

```
def question(person_name, favourite_food):
    return(person_name + ' favourite food is ' + favourite_food)

while True:
    q1 = str(input("Please enter your name:").title())
    if q1 == 'quit':
        break
    if q1 == 'Tom':
        print("My creator favourite food is fried chicken")
    if q1 == 'Sister':
        print("Her favorite food is chicken too")



    q2 =input("Please enter you favourite food:")
    if q2 == 'quit':
        break
    if 'Tom' or 'Sister' in q1:
        questions = question(q1)
        print(questions)


questions = question(q1, q2)
print(questions)
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I want to fix the problems i said on the question

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop in your code so its keep on executing. If you want to quit when user enters "Tom" or "Sister".

You should use:-

```
if q1 == "Tom" or q1 == "Sister":
   break;
```

or you can put these into a list and use "in" operator for the task; like this-

```
dont_ask_list = ["Tom", "Sister"]
if q1 in dont_ask_list:
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the name entry is being convert to title case, the quit will become Quit, which you need to test.

Added elif lines and continue if name not correct.

Testing q1 after favourite food input seems redundant since it has been already tested after name input.

```
def question(person_name, favourite_food):
    return(person_name + ' favourite food is ' + favourite_food)

while True:
    q1 = input("Please enter your name:").title()
    if q1 == 'Quit':
        break
    elif q1 == 'Tom':
        print("My creator favourite food is fried chicken")
    elif q1 == 'Sister':
        print("Her favorite food is chicken too")
    else:
        # Show help and then continue the loop from the while statement.
        print('Choose from Quit, Tom or Sister.')
        continue

    q2 = input("Please enter you favourite food:")
    if q2 == 'Quit':
        break
    # Already tested q1 above.
    #~ if 'Tom' or 'Sister' in q1:

    questions = question(q1, q2)
    print(questions)
```